# How to create GIN index on text array column in SQLAlchemy (with PostgreSQL and python)

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to perform large number of queries to filter by tag, on a postgre table

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String))
```

[This link](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things-part-3.html) recommends storing tags as text array with a GIN index.

How do I add GIN index to above table? Also does it make a difference whether I use `String` vs `Text` datatype?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I solved it by following:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY, array

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Text), nullable=False, default=db.cast(array([], type_=db.Text), ARRAY(db.Text)))
    __table_args__ = (db.Index('ix_post_tags', tags, postgresql_using="gin"), )
```

And query simply by

```
db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.contains([tag]))
```

Have to keep the array type to `Text` and not `String` otherwise some error happens

Comment: `String` can also be queried by using casting: `db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.contains(cast([tag], ARRAY(String)))`. Imports required: `from sqlalchemy import String`,
`from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY`